# Create empty object in R

Tags: r, object

I'm trying to create empty numeric object like this

```
corr <- cor()
```

to use it later on in a loop.
but, it keep returning this error
`Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`.

Here is my full script:

```
EVI <- "D:\\Modis_EVI\\Original\\EVI_Stack_single5000.tif"
y.EVI <- brick(EVI)
m.EVI.cropped <- as.matrix(y.EVI)
time <- 1:nlayers(y.EVI)
corr <- cor()

inf2NA <- function(x) { x[is.infinite(x)] <- NA; x }
for (i in 1:nrow(m.EVI.cropped)){
        EVI.m   <- m.EVI.cropped[i,]
        time    <- 1:nlayers(y.EVI) 
        Corr[i] <- cor(EVI.m, time, method="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
}
```

Any advice please?

Comment: In principle, `cor()` is a function and not a data-structure that you need to initialize.

Comment: `cor` is vectorized and accepts matrix input. Read the documentation. You don't need a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are asking for advice:

It is very likely that you don't need to do this since you can probably use (i) a vectorized function or (ii) a `lapply` loop that pre-allocates the return object for you. If you insist on using a `for` loop, set it up properly. This means you should pre-allocate which you can, e.g., do by using `corr <- numeric(n)`, where `n` is the number of iterations. Appending to a vector is extremely slooooooow.

Answer (score 3):

We can create empty objects with `numeric(0)`, `logical(0)`, `character(0)` etc.

For example

```
num_vec <- numeric(0)
```

creates an empty numeric vector that can be filled up later on:

```
num_vec[1] <- 2
num_vec
# [1] 2
num_vec[2] <- 1
num_vec
# [1] 2 1
```

Comment: Probably `numeric(length = 0)` is more clear, as `numeric(0)` could be confused with "create a numeric object with value 0" by beginners.